# использование sleep для IP

Tags: php

доброго

вопрос теоретический. хочу понять как работает задержка. допустим я поставил на определенной странице сайта

```
sleep(1);
```

допустим, нехороший человек начинает перебирать пароли, ну или просто давить кнопку F5, заставляя сайт перезагружаться, и соответственно тянуть ресурсы хостинга

```
человек_1 обратился к сайту в 0,01 сек ( обращение 1 )
человек_1 обратился к сайту в 0,02 сек ( обращение 2 )
человек_1 обратился к сайту в 0,03 сек ( обращение 3 )
человек_1 обратился к сайту в 0,04 сек ( обращение 4 )
человек_1 обратился к сайту в 0,05 сек ( обращение 5 )
```

Думал, sleep тормознет выполнение кода сайта для этого пользователя ( IP ), и выполнит обращение 1, остальные не дойдут. Реальность - дошли все обращения, и все с задержкой в 1 секунду

Вопрос: Как можно создать задержку для сайта для определенного IP, средствами желательно PHP ? и вообще можно ли?

p.s. я конечно могу написать, для чего спрашиваю, но обсуждение пойдет в сторону ответов, которые я уже вычитал на этом сайте ( благо поиск работает )

p.p.s. можно конечно писать IP в БД/Сессию, потом раздавать задержки по этим данным, но это медленно

Comment: `sleep` делает паузу в работе скрипта и ничего более. что вы вообще подразумеваете под "создать задержку" ?

Comment: а другие команды по мимо sleep описанное умеют делать? просто sleep единственное что нашел

Comment: а мне пока не понятно. чего вы хотите вообще добиться.

Comment: Такие вещи обычно делаеются не на PHP. А если хочется на PHP - то можно посмотреть по ключевым словам flood control и т.п.

Comment: flood control - ок. спрашиваю про PHP, т.к. остальное вычитал уже на stackoverflow

Comment: Защита от F5 делается одним способом (что у вас сервер медленный, или вы не умеете писать быстрые скрипты? тогда включите кеширование.), от перебора паролей - другим (через PHP + БД).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для каждого обращения фиксируем айпи (или как вы там хотите их различать) и время обращения, сохраняем куда-нибудь (например, в базу данных или какую-нибудь глобальную переменную).
2. Каждое обращение сравниваем с базой - если айпи в базе отсутствует, то обрабатываем и запоминаем время обращения. Если присутствует, то сравниваем время предыдущего обращения с текущим. Если промежуток меньше 1 секунды, то ничего не делаем. Если больше - обрабатываем и сохраняем новое время.

Comment: Так себе решение. Многие сидят за NAT и имеют серые IP. Это значит, что если в твоем доме/районе/городе кто-то еще только что зашел на сайт, тебя "заблокируют".

Comment: @TotalPusher Значит, заблокируют, согласен. Но такова была задача - сделать задержку для определенного айпи. PS. А некоторые сайты наверное до сих пор такой метод и используют.

Comment: Я видел такие решения, и даже ставил - "Антиддос для бедных" на шаредхостингах, чтобы хостер не ругался. ТС не говорит зачем ему такое решение. Вариантов масса, и все они "неправильные". Нагрузка с сервера снимается не так (если вас могут заддосить через F5, может быть стоить что-то поменять в скриптах?). От перебора паролей - рекаптча. От скачивания типа wget в режиме паука / teleport pro / прочего вообще, имхо, не надо защищаться, если захотят, вас скачают другим способом. Ладно, ждем ТС